# Several request handlers for a single url

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

Typical way to link a request handler to a URL looks like this:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', RequestHandler1)]
```

If I would like to link several request handlers to a single URL. Is this possible? I was thinking something like this:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', (RequestHandler1, RequestHandler2)]
```

Comment: What would you want this to do? What's the point?

Comment: On a single URL I would like to have two post methods which save data into two separate datastore models.

Comment: Why do you need two handlers for that? Why not do it in one method?

Comment: I though it makes more sense(as making the code more modular) to have these two actions separated according to the business logic. For example, this made more sense to me: `RequestHandler1.post(business logic 1), RequestHandler2.post(business logic 2)` rather than `requestHandler.post(if x: business logic 1 else business logic 2)`

Comment: Which request handler should return the response? What happens if they both respond?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regex match to match the url parameter

for example:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/([a-z]+)', RequestHandler1), # matched the word parameter
    ('/([0-9]+)', RequestHandler2) # matched the numeric parameter
]
```

so, you can separate the business logic based on parameter condition...

alternatives, why not u set up the get parameters?

```
/application?paramcondition="A" --> URL
/application?paramcondition="0" --> URL

class blabla(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      param = self.request.get("paramcondition")

      if param == "A":
         # do something
      elif param == "0":
         # do another
```

so you only need 1 URL handler...